# How to fetch document name from Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to fetch a document name "abcd".

[image]

```
await _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("name", isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userMap = value.docs[0].data();
      });
    });
```

.uid is not providing the document "abcd". How can I get it?
Only need the name of document.

Comment: If you `print(_auth.currentUser?.uid)` right before the query, and then `print(value.docs[0].data())` in the `then`, what do those print?

Answer (score 0):

That name `"abcd"` is the document id in your Firestore database, if you need to access it you will need to set the document id as its name which you look in the Firestore database :

```
await _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc("abcd")
        .get() ; // this will get you the abcd document
```

and if you want to query your collection based on uid, and get the document information from it, first you will need a field called `"name"` which it's value id the user's uid, then :

```
await _firestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("name", isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser?.uid)
        .get(querySnapshot).then(() {
         final document = querySnapshot.docs.first; 
         print(document.id); // this will print abcd
         });
```